# Why Apple OS, Software and so many things are highly stable and smooth?

Tags: macos, windows, software

Even when using Windows on high end computers it lacks is stability when using many programs. I want to know how apple manage to provide such grate experience to users, even not running apple macos (mojave/Big sur) on apple hardware. I have tested macos on another hardware as it grate and nearly same in performance and stability running on SSD, Nvidia 710, 16GB RAM.

Comment: Apple makes programmers use memory etc in its "standard", like cmnd+p is print. They have done this for years. Go back to the pc's when memory could be defined as "extended" or "expanded" and different programs addressed specific memory locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd question your premise that Windows is inherently unstable: it is used in all sorts of business and industry environments where stability is critical.

And indeed, there are those who would question whether Apple's software is all it should be right now.

However, the usual answer to this sort of question is that Apple makes both the hardware and the software, so that the two are designed for each other. Also, there is a much smaller range of hardware devices that need to be supported.

Windows is built to run on a much larger range of hardware, often relying on third-party drivers to bridge any gaps between the OS and the hardware.

Comment: Does C++ and Objective C are also involved in this?

Comment: @AdarshRaj There's nothing inherently more stable about those languages.